# How to show progress bar with percentage inside a table using Powershell?

Tags: powershell, winforms, progress-bar

I have a windows form contain of table. I need to show the progress bar inside of overview column. The progress bar that I expect is bar with percentage number.

But the code that I had is, the GUI will pop up once this process ' Start-Process .\Utility.exe /getconfig:.\UUT.log -Windowstyle Minimized' finished.
My expectation is once the code start running, the GUI will pop up and progress bar will show from 0 - 100%.

Here is my code.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Get the screen's working area size
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea

# Create the main form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

# Set form properties
$form.Text = "MYGUI"
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedDialog
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
$form.WindowState = [System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState]::Maximized
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($screen.Width, $screen.Height)

$form.BackColor = '#F2F2F2'

# Set form icon
$iconPath = "C:\1.0\xx.ico"  
if (Test-Path $iconPath) {
    $icon = New-Object System.Drawing.Icon($iconPath)
    $form.Icon = $icon
}

# Calculate dimensions for the sub-form (1/4 of the main form)
$subViewWidth = [math]::Round($form.Width / 1.5)
$subViewHeight = [math]::Round($form.Height / 1.5)
$subViewLeft = [math]::Round(($form.Width - $subViewWidth) / 2)
$subViewTop = [math]::Round(($form.Height - $subViewHeight) / 2.5)

# Create a Panel to act as the sub-form
$subView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$subView.Width = $subViewWidth
$subView.Height = $subViewHeight
$subView.BackColor = '#FFFFFF'
$subView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($subViewLeft, $subViewTop)

# Add the Panel to the main form
$form.Controls.Add($subView)

# Create a DataGridView
$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Width = $subViewWidth - 20  # Adjusting width for padding
$dataGridView.Height = $subViewHeight - 40  # Adjusting height for padding
$dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode]::Fill
$dataGridView.ReadOnly = $true  # Disallow user input
$dataGridView.BackgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
$dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = "#0096D6"

$dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = "#FFFFFF" # Change header font color
$dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)  # Change header font style and size

# Define columns for the DataGridView (same as before)
$stepColumn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn
$stepColumn.HeaderText = "Step"
$stepColumn.Name = "Step"
$stepCellTemplate = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell
$stepColumn.CellTemplate = $stepCellTemplate

$overviewColumn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn
$overviewColumn.HeaderText = "Overview"
$overviewColumn.Name = "Overview"
$overviewCellTemplate = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell
$overviewColumn.CellTemplate = $overviewCellTemplate

$messageColumn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn
$messageColumn.HeaderText = "Message"
$messageColumn.Name = "Message"
$messageCellTemplate = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell
$messageColumn.CellTemplate = $messageCellTemplate

# Create the progress bar 
$progressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$progressBar.Width = $subViewWidth - 40  
$progressBar.Height = 20

# Add columns to the DataGridView
$dataGridView.Columns.Add($stepColumn)
$dataGridView.Columns.Add($overviewColumn)
$dataGridView.Columns.Add($messageColumn)

# Position the DataGridView in the middle of the sub-form
$dataGridView.Left = ($subViewWidth - $dataGridView.Width) / 2
$dataGridView.Top = ($subViewHeight - $dataGridView.Height) / 2

# Add progress bar to panel
$subView.Controls.Add($progressBar) 
$progressBar.Top = $dataGridView.Bottom + 10
$progressBar.Left = ($subViewWidth - $progressBar.Width) / 2

# Add the DataGridView to the sub-form
$subView.Controls.Add($dataGridView)


####### Start Process #######

# Create the progress bar 
$progressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
$progressBar.Width = $subViewWidth - 40  
$progressBar.Height = 20

# Other form initialization code 

# Add progress bar to panel
$subView.Controls.Add($progressBar) 
$progressBar.Top = $dataGridView.Bottom + 10
$progressBar.Left = ($subViewWidth - $progressBar.Width) / 2

####### Start Process #######

# Get UUT info
$Step_1 = "Get UUT info"

# Show progress bar  
$progressBar.Value = 0
$progressBar.Visible = $true

try {
    # Update progress bar while command runs
    Start-Process .\Utility.exe /getconfig:.\UUT.log -Windowstyle Minimized
    
    for ($i = 1; $i -le 100; $i++) {
       Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50  
       $progressBar.Value = $i
    }

    # Check if UUT.log exists
    $logFilePath = ".\UUT.log"
    if (Test-Path $logFilePath) {
        # Add result row 
        $dataGridView.Rows.Add("$Step_1", "Passed", "Success") 
    }
} catch {
    $dataGridView.Rows.Add("$Step_1", "Failed", "Error message")
}

# Hide progress bar
$progressBar.Visible = $false 

$form.ShowDialog()
```

anyone can help me to give an idea on this? Thank you!

##Updated

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# Get the screen's working area size
$screen = [System.Windows.Forms.Screen]::PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea

# Create the main form
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form

# Set form properties
$form.Text = "PM"
$form.FormBorderStyle = [System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle]::FixedDialog
$form.StartPosition = [System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition]::CenterScreen
$form.WindowState = [System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState]::Maximized
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size($screen.Width, $screen.Height)

$form.BackColor = '#F2F2F2'

# Set form icon
$iconPath = "C:\1.0\HHH.ico"  # Replace this with the path to your icon file
if (Test-Path $iconPath) {
    $icon = New-Object System.Drawing.Icon($iconPath)
    $form.Icon = $icon
}

# Calculate dimensions for the sub-form (1/4 of the main form)
$subViewWidth = [math]::Round($form.Width / 1.5)
$subViewHeight = [math]::Round($form.Height / 1.5)
$subViewLeft = [math]::Round(($form.Width - $subViewWidth) / 2)
$subViewTop = [math]::Round(($form.Height - $subViewHeight) / 2.5)

# Create a Panel to act as the sub-form
$subView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Panel
$subView.Width = $subViewWidth
$subView.Height = $subViewHeight
$subView.BackColor = '#FFFFFF'
$subView.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($subViewLeft, $subViewTop)

# Add the Panel to the main form
$form.Controls.Add($subView)

$font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Calibri", 9, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold, [System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit]::Pixel)

# Create a DataGridView
$dataGridView = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$dataGridView.Width = $subViewWidth - 20  # Adjusting width for padding
$dataGridView.Height = $subViewHeight - 40  # Adjusting height for padding
$dataGridView.AutoSizeColumnsMode = [System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode]::Fill
$dataGridView.ReadOnly = $true  # Disallow user input
$dataGridView.BackgroundColor = "#FFFFFF"
$dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = "#0096D6"
$dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = "#FFFFFF" # Change header font color
$dataGridView.ColumnHeadersDefaultCellStyle.Font = New-Object System.Drawing.Font("Tahoma", 9, [System.Drawing.FontStyle]::Bold)  # Change header font style and size

# Define columns for the DataGridView (same as before)
$stepColumn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn
$stepColumn.HeaderText = "Step"
$stepColumn.Name = "Step"
$stepCellTemplate = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell
$stepColumn.CellTemplate = $stepCellTemplate

$overviewColumn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn
$overviewColumn.HeaderText = "Overview"
$overviewColumn.Name = "Overview"
$overviewCellTemplate = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell
$overviewColumn.CellTemplate = $overviewCellTemplate

$messageColumn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn
$messageColumn.HeaderText = "Message"
$messageColumn.Name = "Message"
$messageCellTemplate = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell
$messageColumn.CellTemplate = $messageCellTemplate

# Add columns to the DataGridView
$dataGridView.Columns.Add($stepColumn)
$dataGridView.Columns.Add($overviewColumn)
$dataGridView.Columns.Add($messageColumn)

# Position the DataGridView in the middle of the sub-form
$dataGridView.Left = ($subViewWidth - $dataGridView.Width) / 2
$dataGridView.Top = ($subViewHeight - $dataGridView.Height) / 2

# Add the DataGridView to the sub-form
$subView.Controls.Add($dataGridView)

# Add progress bar
$progressBar = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ProgressBar
# $progressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(10, 50)
$progressBar.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(($subViewWidth / 3.8), 20)

# Calculate the position of the Overview column in the DataGridView
$overviewColumnIndex = $dataGridView.Columns["Overview"].Index
$overviewColumnLeft = $dataGridView.GetCellDisplayRectangle($overviewColumnIndex, -1, $true).Location.X

# Calculate the position of the progress bar within the sub-form
$progressBarLeft = $overviewColumnLeft + $dataGridView.Left + $subViewLeft + ($subViewWidth / 11) + 5
$progressBarTop = $dataGridView.Top + $dataGridView.ColumnHeadersHeight - 18  # Adjust this value to position the progress bar as needed

# Set the position of the progress bar
$progressBar.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point($progressBarLeft, $progressBarTop)
$dataGridView.Controls.Add($progressBar)

# Add progress bar label
$progressLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$progressLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(($subViewWidth / 1.6), ($progressBarTop + 6)) 
$progressLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(50, 9)
$progressLabel.Text = "0%"
$progressLabel.TextAlign = [System.Drawing.ContentAlignment]::MiddleCenter
$progressBar.BackColor = "#FFFFFF"
$dataGridView.Controls.Add($progressLabel)

$form.Show()
 

######## Main Process ##########

# Get UUT Info
function GetUUTInfo {
    $logFilePath = ".\UU.log"
    if (Test-Path $logFilePath) {
        $progressBar.Value = 100
        $dataGridView.Rows.Add("Retrieve Test Unit Information", "", "Passed") 
        $progressLabel.Text = "100%"
       
    } else {
        $progressBar.Value = 100
        $dataGridView.Rows.Add("Retrieve Test Unit Information", "Failed", "The UUT.log file couldn't be found")
        $progressLabel.Text = "Error"
    }
}
try {
    $process = Start-Process .\Utility.exe /getconfig:.\UU.log -Windowstyle Minimized -PassThru -Wait

    # Call the function to check progress
    GetUUTInfo
} catch {
    GetUUTInfo
}

# File Existing Check
$xml     = ".\dr.xml"
$Reset_1    = ".\Tools\$Env:processor_architecture\cPS.dll"
$Reset_2    = ".\Tools\$Env:processor_architecture\Reset.exe"
$SyncTool = ".\Sync.exe"

$requiredFiles = @($xml, $Reset_1, "$Reset_2", "$SyncTool")
foreach ($file in $requiredFiles) {
    $n = 0
    if (Test-Path -Path $file){
        $n++
        $progressBar.Value = 100
        $dataGridView.Rows.Add("Check Required File", "", "Passed") 
        $progressLabel.Text = "100%"
    } else {
        $progressBar.Value = 100
        $dataGridView.Rows.Add("Check Required File", "Failed", "The $file file couldn't be found")
        $progressLabel.Text = "Error"
    }
}




Start-Sleep -s 10
$form.Dispose()
```

I updated my code, with this code, I am able to perform the progress bar in the `Overview` column, but it only perform for the first column only. But my process will be more than 1, so I need to perform the progress bar in the `Overview` column depends on the process I have.

Anyone can help me to share an idea about this?
I really appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Showing a Control inside the Cells of a DataGridView the *canonical way* is not that simple. You need a custom DataGridViewColumn which handles a dedicated template, created using a custom DatagGridViewCell that hosts the Control. You might probably find it simpler if you create a standard Column with a suitable drawing surface, e.g., a custom DataGridViewImageColumn, then override its Paint event and draw the progress yourself. You can do that in your own style, or use the `ProgressBarRenderer` to paint a standard ProgressBar (it renders the progress in chunks, which you need to specify)

Answer (score 0):

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-progress?view=powershell-7.4

Your best bet is `Write-Progress` but if that is giving you issues you can create custom `DataGridViewProgressBarCell` and `DataGridViewProgressBarColumn`

```
# Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

# ... (your existing code)

# Create a DataGridViewProgressBarCell
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class DataGridViewProgressBarCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    protected override void Paint(Graphics graphics, Rectangle clipBounds, Rectangle cellBounds, int rowIndex, DataGridViewElementStates cellState, object value, object formattedValue, string errorText, DataGridViewCellStyle cellStyle, DataGridViewAdvancedBorderStyle advancedBorderStyle, DataGridViewPaintParts paintParts)
    {
        int progressVal = (int)value;
        float percentage = ((float)progressVal / 100.0f); 
        Brush backColorBrush = new SolidBrush(cellStyle.BackColor);
        Brush foreColorBrush = new SolidBrush(cellStyle.ForeColor);

        base.Paint(graphics, clipBounds, cellBounds, rowIndex, cellState, value, formattedValue, errorText, cellStyle, advancedBorderStyle, paintParts);

        graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(22, 160, 133)), cellBounds.X + 2, cellBounds.Y + 2, Convert.ToInt32((percentage * cellBounds.Width - 4)), cellBounds.Height - 4);
        graphics.DrawString(progressVal + "%", cellStyle.Font, foreColorBrush, cellBounds.X+(cellBounds.Width/2), cellBounds.Y+2);
    }
}
"@ -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms

# Create a DataGridViewProgressBarColumn
Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class DataGridViewProgressBarColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public DataGridViewProgressBarColumn()
    {
        this.CellTemplate = new DataGridViewProgressBarCell();
    }
}
"@ -ReferencedAssemblies System.Windows.Forms

# ... (your existing code)

# Define columns for the DataGridView
$stepColumn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn
$stepColumn.HeaderText = "Step"
$stepColumn.Name = "Step"
$stepCellTemplate = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell
$stepColumn.CellTemplate = $stepCellTemplate

$overviewColumn = New-Object DataGridViewProgressBarColumn
$overviewColumn.HeaderText = "Overview"
$overviewColumn.Name = "Overview"

$messageColumn = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn
$messageColumn.HeaderText = "Message"
$messageColumn.Name = "Message"
$messageCellTemplate = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxCell
$messageColumn.CellTemplate = $messageCellTemplate

# ... (your existing code)

# Start Process
$Step_1 = "Get UUT info"

# Show progress bar
$progressBar.Value = 0
$progressBar.Visible = $true

try {
    # Update progress bar while command runs
    $process = Start-Process .\Utility.exe /getconfig:.\UUT.log -Windowstyle Minimized -PassThru
    while (!$process.HasExited) {
        Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 50
        $progressBar.Value = [math]::Min($progressBar.Value + 1, 100)
        $dataGridView.Rows.Add("$Step_1", $progressBar.Value, "Running")
    }

    # Check if UUT.log exists
    $logFilePath = ".\UUT.log"
    if (Test-Path $logFilePath) {
        # Add result row
        $dataGridView.Rows.Add("$Step_1", 100, "Success")
    }
} catch {
    $dataGridView.Rows.Add("$Step_1", 0, "Error message")
}

# Hide progress bar
$progressBar.Visible = $false 

$form.ShowDialog()
```

Try this and let me know if this helps.

Comment: HI @Martin thanks for your advice. Appreciated. But still  not meet my expectation and encounter some errors. I updated my code